# Discrepancies in data unzipping via Google Colab

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have been using Google Drive and Colab for the past few years and never faced any issues while unzipping files via Colab into Drive.

But its been a second day I am facing errors while unzipping files. I uploaded a zip file to Google Drive with 15000 image files. When I unzip these files using `!unzip` command on Colab, it displays all files are successfully unzipped. But these files are not showing on Google Drive. Only a single folder is being displayed with some files.

I checked through python code and linux commands on Colab, files are present certainly but I can not view them in Google Drive. I am trying to train a vision transformer for a medical image classification task. I am using PyTorch and when I displayed the `len(dataloaders)` it display just 175 files although I have 15k files. The train and test loader should display respective files but I am not sure and have no idea what's happening here.

```
# Create datasets and dataloaders
train_dataset = ImageFolder(train_dir, transform=data_transforms)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)

val_dataset = ImageFolder(val_dir, transform=data_transforms)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, num_workers=4)

print(len(train_loader))
print(len(val_loader))
```

Anyone else facing similar problems? Or any solution to this problem?

P.S: I have checked the directory structure and there is no issue regarding directory structure. In addition I used following command to make sure I have required number of images in current directory.

```
!ls -l | grep "^-" | wc -l
```

This results in 3250 files, but surprisingly the folder does not exist on Google Drive although I unzipped it. I waited for more than a day thinking it might be Gdrive cache problem. But I got no clue. Any help or information in this regard shall be highly appreciated.